# What are the rate limits for GitHub Apps?

Tags: github

I'm trying to interpret the [Rate limits for GitHub Apps documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/developers/apps/rate-limits-for-github-apps). Is the limit for your app, no matter how many orgs where it is installed, or is the limit for each organization that installs it?

For example, let's say I created the GitHub app "foo". GitHub organizations "bar" and "biz" install my app "foo".

1. Do I have 5,000 minimum rate limit for API calls against the GitHub org "bar", and a separate 5,000 minimum rate limit for API calls against the GitHub org "biz"?
2. Or do I have a 5,000 minimum rate limit against the orgs "bar" and "biz" combined?

The way I read the doc, it sounds like the first case. But we seeing failures in a prod environment that seem to indicate it might be the second case. We're still trying to narrow it down, but checking if anybody knows for sure.

Thanks,

Charles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had asked the same question to GitHub support and got an answer -- the answer is number 1 -- the limit is per installation target.